# How to set NW js Window always in background in kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nwjs

I am running an NW js application in kiosk mode,and i am giving option to launch native windows desktop apps from it,
Issue:-
After i am launching the child application ,if i click any where in the body of nw js application,the child application window is going background of nwjs window,

Looking for:
How to set NWjs window always in background ,if child window opens it should be in foreground until it minimize,

Thank you
Sandeep KS

Comment: would temporarily leaving kiosk mode be an option?

Comment: sorry! it should be a kiosk mode application

Comment: yes - and clearly kiosk mode has some shortcomings for your use case - which is why I made the suggestion I made. you mention `windows desktop apps` so this app is in windows, right. As far as I am aware, Windows has no "below all" attribute that you can apply to a window to make it the bottom most window, so your chances are not good

Comment: however, having said that, in windows there is a function that sends the window to the bottom most position - `SendToBack()` - perhaps you can make a suggestion to the nice people at NWjs to implement such a thing (if possible)

Comment: Thankyou for you reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a  child application with following c# code ,and run that child process from nwjs application

SetWindowPos can make windows AlwaysOnTop. Most likely it can give the opposite result. Try something along these lines:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,
   int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);


 public const uint SWP_NOSIZE          = 0x0001;
 public const uint SWP_NOMOVE          = 0x0002;
 public const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE      = 0x0010;
 public const int HWND_BOTTOM = 1;


SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```